# Parsing a List of Objects in Flutter error

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am using code generation to help with working with JSON files. I am wanting to parse a list of objects, but I keep getting the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

The Json file I want to deserialize (I've already created models files for the json):

```
[
  {
  "id": "Nebula",
  "setCount": "5 - 3",
  "characters": {
    "char1": "mario",
    "char2": "peach"
     },
  "notes": "this player has really cool combos and float cancel nairs are cool"
  },
  {
    "id": "Kambo",
    "setCount": "2 - 8",
    "characters": {
      "char1": "fox",
      "char2": ""
       },
    "notes": "I play fox for fun lmao"
  },
  {
    "id": "Quiet",
    "setCount": "8 - 3",
    "characters": {
      "char1": "zero_suit_samus",
      "char2": "wolf"
       },
    "notes": "this player has really cool combos and float cancel nairs are cool"
  }
]
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the where I call to receive a Playlist from the Json:

```
void setupHomePage() async {
    PlayerList playerList = await getPlayerList();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Home(),
        settings: RouteSettings(
          arguments: playerList,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Decoding the JSON:

```
PlayerList playerList;

Future<String> _loadPlayerListAsset () async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/nebula.json');
}

Future loadPlayerList () async {
  String jsonString = await _loadPlayerListAsset();
  final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(jsonString);
  playerList = PlayerList.fromJson(jsonResponse);
}

Future<PlayerList> getPlayerList() async {
  await loadPlayerList();
  print(playerList.toString());
  return playerList;
}
```

Generated JSON code:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class PlayerList {
  PlayerList (
      this.players
      );

  List<Player> players;

  factory PlayerList.fromJson (Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PlayerListFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PlayerListToJson(this);

}


PlayerList _$PlayerListFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return PlayerList(
    (json['players'] as List)
        ?.map((e) =>
            e == null ? null : Player.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList(),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$PlayerListToJson(PlayerList instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'players': instance.players?.map((e) => e?.toJson())?.toList(),
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `jsonResponse` here:

```
final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```

Is `List` since your JSON defines a list of maps.

But then you are doing:

```
playerList = PlayerList.fromJson(jsonResponse);
...
factory PlayerList.fromJson (Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PlayerListFromJson(json);
```

The signature of your `fromJson` are saying it takes a `Map<String, dynamic>` which are not compatible with `List`.

The next problem will be `json['players']` which are not going to work since your JSON does not contain any key with the name `players`. Also, your JSON are a `List` so it makes no sense.

**Example on how to parse the provided JSON**

I have make the following code which can parse the JSON you have provided as example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Player {
  String id;
  String setCount;
  Map<String, String> characters;
  String notes;

  Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'] as String,
        setCount = json['setCount'] as String,
        characters = (json['characters'] as Map).cast<String, String>(),
        notes = json['notes'] as String;

  static List<Player> getPlayersFromJson(List<dynamic> json) =>
      json.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>().map((j) => Player.fromJson(j)).toList();

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
        'id': id,
        'setCount': setCount,
        'characters': characters,
        'notes': notes
      };
}

void main() {
  const jsonString = '''
[
  {
  "id": "Nebula",
  "setCount": "5 - 3",
  "characters": {
    "char1": "mario",
    "char2": "peach"
     },
  "notes": "this player has really cool combos and float cancel nairs are cool"
  },
  {
    "id": "Kambo",
    "setCount": "2 - 8",
    "characters": {
      "char1": "fox",
      "char2": ""
       },
    "notes": "I play fox for fun lmao"
  },
  {
    "id": "Quiet",
    "setCount": "8 - 3",
    "characters": {
      "char1": "zero_suit_samus",
      "char2": "wolf"
       },
    "notes": "this player has really cool combos and float cancel nairs are cool"
  }
]
''';

  final playerList = Player.getPlayersFromJson(json.decode(jsonString) as List);

  playerList.forEach((player) => print('${player.id} | ${player.notes}'));
  // Nebula | this player has really cool combos and float cancel nairs are cool
  // Kambo | I play fox for fun lmao
  // Quiet | this player has really cool combos and float cancel nairs are cool

  print(json.encode(playerList));
}
```

Comment: What do you suggest I do? Do I switch the signature to be a List?

Comment: Well, you have written that you code are generated but do not state by what and how. It looks like there are some problem with the JSON schema you have used to generate the source. I must say I have never been fan of generators since I think you can make the parsing manually a lot better in lot of cases (since you can then control the data structure in more details).

Comment: I reworked the JSON structure. Thank you for your input!